# Show that if $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $D$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S\subset D$ is open in $D$ if and only if it is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I'm working through the mathematical appendix of my economics textbook, and am currently attempting some basic topology proofs. I have attempted the following proof, and I was hoping someone could suggest any improvements in my method, formatting, or indeed point out if I have made any mistakes in my reasoning. I have looked through the forums here and found some very similar questions, but I am keen to receive feedback on my approach.

**Question:** Show that if $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $D$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S\subset D$ is open in $D$ if and only if it is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Proof part 1:** Show that $S\subset D$ is open in $D \Rightarrow S\subset D$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1.1. Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let
$S\subset D$ be open in $D$.

1.2. $\exists$ some set $S'\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ that is open in
$\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $S=S'\cap D$.

1.3. Using the theorem that the intersection of a finite number of open sets is itself open, since both $S'$ and $D$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Proof part 2:** Show that $S\subset D$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow S\subset D$ is open in $D$.

2.1 Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let
$S\subset D$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

2.2 $\forall x \in S \hspace{3mm} \exists$ $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\subset S \hspace{3mm}$ (definition of openness in $\mathbb{R}^n$)

2.3 Since $S\subset D$, if $B_\epsilon(x)\subset S$ then $B_\epsilon(x)\cap D\subset S$.

2.4 $B_\epsilon(x)\cap D\subset S \Leftrightarrow S$ is open in $D \hspace{3mm}$ (by the definition of openness in $D$)

I am quite new to this forum, so please let me know if this is an acceptable way to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

$D\subset (\mathbb{R}^n ,\tau_{usual})$

$(D, \tau_D) $ is a topological subspace of $( \mathbb{R}^n ,\tau_{usual})$.

$\tau_D=\{D\cap U :U\in \tau_{usual}\}$

Now it is clear,

$S\in \tau_D \iff S=D\cap U $ for some $U\in \tau_{usual}$

Also since, $D\in \tau_{usual}$, it follows that $S\in \tau_{usual}$

Comment: Thanks for that. I think for the level of math knowledge assumed in the course I'm taking, I'd probably need to spell out some of those assumptions. Topological subspaces are not assumed knowledge.

Comment: @cashman If the concept of "subspace" is not known, what does it mean that $S$ is open in $D$?